# Close TraitsUI window without clicking OK

Tags: python, traits

I am working on an application using TraitsUI.

I need to pop up a window to request some values.

There will be something like a ProcessValues button and a SaveValues button.

- If ProcessValues is clicked, something should be done, then the window should be closed
- If SaveValues is clicked, something else should be done, the window should be closed too.

There should be no OK button

In the example code below, clicking on the buttons makes the messages in the handler be printed, but I don't know what to do to make the window close itself down other than clicking [x] in the frame.

Overloading close() does not seem to do the trick, as it is called AFTER OK is clicked. Maybe there's a way to generate a close_window event, or maybe it is something else.

Can anybody help?

```
from enthought.traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, Str, Int, List, Any, DelegatesTo
from enthought.traits.ui.api import Handler, View, Item, Action

class MyPanelHandler(Handler):
    def _process_values(self, info):
        #>>>reach process_values() through info and call
        print 'values processed OK'
        #>>> what goes here so that the window is closed?
    def _save_values(self, info):
        #>>>reach save_values() through info and call
        print 'values saved OK'
        #>>> what goes here so that the window is closed?

class MyPanel(HasTraits):
    model = Any
    name = Str
    age = Int
    process_values_button = Action(name = 'Process Values', action = '_process_values')
    save_values_button = Action(name = 'Save Params', action = '_save_values')

    view = View( 'name', 'age', handler = MyPanelHandler(),
            buttons = [process_values_button, save_values_button],)

class MyApp(HasTraits):
    panel = Instance(MyPanel)

    def __init__(self):
        self.panel = MyPanel(model = self)
    def get_values(self):
        self.panel.configure_traits()
    def save_values(self, name, age):
        print '... doing whatever to save values'
    def process_values(self):
        print '... doing whatever to process values'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyApp()
    a.get_values()
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution elsewhere. To close the window clicking on an Action that calls a method in a Handler, call "info.ui.dispose()" from the Handler (where info is the sole parameter being passed to the handler method, other than self).

Here is the corrected dummy program; beware of the "if not info.initialized" part -- without it, there may be exceptions thrown if for some reason the uiinfo object takes too long to be populated.

```
from enthought.traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, Str, Int, List, Any, DelegatesTo
from enthought.traits.ui.api import Handler, View, Item, Action

class MyPanelHandler(Handler):
    def _process_values(self, info):
        if not info.initialized: 
            return # do this in case info takes long to initialize
        # invoke methods
        info.object.model.process_values(info.object.name, info.object.age)
        print 'values have been processed'
        info.ui.dispose() # THIS IS WHAT I WAS ACTUALLY ASKING FOR
    def _save_values(self, info):
        if not info.initialized: return
        info.object.model.save_values(info.object.name, info.object.age)
        print 'values have been saved'
        info.ui.dispose()

class MyPanel(HasTraits):
    model = Any
    name = Str
    age = Int
    process_values_button = Action(name = 'Process Values', action = '_process_values')
    save_values_button = Action(name = 'Save Params', action = '_save_values')   
    view = View( 'name', 'age', handler = MyPanelHandler(),
            buttons = [process_values_button, save_values_button],)

class MyApp(HasTraits):
    panel = Instance(MyPanel)
    def __init__(self):
        self.panel = MyPanel(model = self)
    def get_values(self):
        self.panel.configure_traits()
    def save_values(self, name, age):
        print '... saving (%s, %s)' % (name, age)
    def process_values(self, name, age):
        print '... processing (%s, %s)' % (name, age)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyApp()
    a.get_values()
```